# zombie.js and socket.io (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, socket.io, zombie.js

I would like to test my node.js/socket.io application using the zombie.js headless browser.

Unfortunately when the zombie.js app connects to my app it reports a load of connection/disconnection events.

Eg.

```
Zombie: Firing timeout 234, delay: 1000
Zombie: GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1313487267750&jsonp=68
Zombie: GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/1/?t=1313487267724&jsonp=69
connected
connected
connected
Zombie: Firing timeout 237, delay: 2000
Zombie: Firing timeout 226, delay: 16000
Zombie: Firing timeout 218, delay: 25000
disconnected
```

It seems Zombie doesn't respect timeout delays, so I wonder if this could be a cause?

Has anyone tried using zombie with socket.io or can tell me why zombie seems to fire timeouts immediately rather than waiting the stated time?

Comment: Are you sure that's not zombie emulating XHR to keep the socket.io connection open?

Comment: Yes, likely. I've updated the question with a better example. I think the issue may be that the XHR requests do not occur after the stated timeout delay, and instead happen at once.

Comment: @bdis this may be a limitation of zombie. Try reproducing it with phantomjs

Comment: @Raynos Phantomjs works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I also believe you can test your socket.io code with the latest version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap this up: I used Phantomjs as recommended by @Raynos which works nicely.

Comment: I met with same scenario you faced with Zombie, do you have any reference on using PhantomJS for ajax testing?

Comment: I mean for ajax/socket.io implementatin testing